# SessionFactory exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

Getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required` in my spring boot + hibernate 5 application. I try to autowire it like this

```
@Autowired
    public void setupSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        getHibernateTemplate().setCheckWriteOperations(false);
    }
```

And also i tried to add stuff like this to my config file

```
 @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        return new LocalSessionFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sf) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sf);
    }
```

My application.yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: password
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `return new LocalSessionFactoryBean().getObject();` returns null.

This method simply returns internal field value:

```
public SessionFactory getObject() {
        return this.sessionFactory;
}
```

which is null be default.

Session factory needed to be configured: dataSource should be setup, package to scan, hibernate properties. [Something like that](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring):

```
   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] { "org.baeldung.spring.persistence.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }
```

Comment: error changed to:
Description:

Field ownerRepository in com.jgang.realestate.service.OwnerServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: I have no idea what is `com.jgang.realestate.service.OwnerServiceImpl`, but it is definitely different problem, while question's problem is solved

Comment: and btw, i can use application.yml to setup datasource and hibernate properties?

Comment: OwnerServiceImpl is service, which use dao

Comment: Do you think I see how does this class look like? Too many questions in one topic. Create new question and describe there new problem.

Comment: Service use dao like  @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository ownerRepository;
The case is that anyother solution I tried before alternated these 2 errors